# CSS Problem to make 2 divs float side by side

Tags: css

I would like 2 divs, which are within a container div, to appear side-by-side.  However the second one wraps for some reason.  The 2nd div promo is below and to the right the 1st div slideshow.  The margin seems correct, but I want these two divs to appear side-by-side.

I've tried some of the suggestions on here but they do not work.

Here is the CSS:

```
#top-feature {
background: red;
height: 320px;
width: 897px;
margin: 11px 0 0 0;
/*padding: 10px 0 0 10px;*/
position: relative;
text-align: left;
}

#slideshow {
height: 300px;
width: 548px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
background: blue;
}

#promo {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 0 0 569px;
background: green;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div id="top-feature">
        <div id="slideshow">
        </div>
        <div id="promo">
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float, inline or position:absolute those inner divs if you want them side-by-side. A "normal" div is a block object which forces following content to appear below it.

Comment: I tried doing that, which didnt work.  slideshow float left and promo floated right.

Comment: but did you remove the 569px margin on promo first?

Comment: So I cant use margins at all with Float?  Petah's solution seems to work, but I need to use the margins as well, I think.

Comment: position: absolute seems to work, and I can use the margins without float

Comment: sure you can use margins but without absolute positioning the margin is relative to the right edge of the left inner div. Therefore a 569px left margin will not fit in the available space so it wraps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `float` css property

```
#top-feature {
    background: red;
    height: 320px;
    width: 897px;
}

#top-feature div {
    float: left;
}

#slideshow {
    height: 300px;
    width: 548px;
    background: blue;
}

#promo {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/K64vZ/

Comment: I tried that which seems to work, but how can I use the margin also?

Comment: Yea thats a pretty cool site.  Ok so I settled with position: absolute, able to use the margins, and not use float.

Comment: @Paul, what wrong with using float? You can still set margins. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/K64vZ/1/

Comment: Im not familiar enough with Float.  It seems that with absolute there is no question, which should work in the major browsers correct?

Answer (score 0):

first be sure to float, or you could also use absolute positions:

```
    #slideshow {
height: 300px;
width: 548px;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
background: blue;
float: left;
}

#promo {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 0 0 569px;
background: green;
float: left;
}
```

Then make sure you have some contents in each div.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any special styling to achieve that, it is by default property of css.

The two divs will always be side by side until the total width of the two divs is not more than the container div or you have explicitly used clear:both; with the first div. Here is an example :

```
#outerdiv {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
#innerdiv1 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
}
#innerdiv2 {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

If you haven't specify any borders, these will be displayed side by side, but if you have specified borders/padding/margins etc. you have to then adjust the width of inner divs accordingly.