# 2 divs alongside in a page

Tags: css, html

I need to position 2 divs alongside, first's width %20 of the page and second's width %80 of the page. I don't know which position I must give divs. Relative, fixed, absolute, inherit?

How can I do it?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882206/css-problem-to-make-2-divs-float-side-by-side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387392/how-to-get-these-two-divs-side-by-side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803023/how-to-place-two-divs-next-to-each-other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683254/align-2-divs-side-by-side

Comment: @Erdinc Before asking question do a search and try to see related answers first...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
.firstdiv{
width:20%;
float:left;
}
.secdiv{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SB7dn/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't give any position to divs just use `float:left;` and set the width to 80%(or 79%) and 20% as usual

```
div_first
{
float:left;
width:79%;
}
div_second
{
float:left;
width:20%;
}
```